# Настройки и параметры безопасности MS SQL

Tags: безопасность, sql-server

Пожалуйста, ответьте на следующие вопросы из пяти пунктов:

1. Где хранятся системные настройки MS SQL (данные из `DatabaseSettingspageofSQLServerProperties`)
2. Какой алгоритм используется для хеширования паролей MS SQL
3. Где хранятся настройки резервного копирования (расписание и параметры)
4. Каким образом можно выяснить какие права даны пользователю (системные привилегии, права на таблицы и тп)
5. Где хранится информация о линкованных БД (т.е. текущий статус соединения, параметры подключения)

Answer (score 2):

1. В базе master. Смотреть вьюхи sys.
2. Не в курсе. В принципе вариантов не так много MD либо SHASHA1
3. В базе msdb. Там лежат все данные агента и других служб
4. Ну если речь не о том, чтобы тупо посмотреть в менеджере, можно запросить sys-таблицы (или как рекомендовано MS - вьюхи sys.), например sysusers. А также серию процедур безопасности
5. вьюха sys.servers